# Pygame TMX file not loading

Tags: pygame, tmxtiledmap

I have been working on a KidsCanCode project in pygame(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UxnelT9aCo&list=PLsk-HSGFjnaGQq7ybM8Lgkh5EMxUWPm2i) and I've finished everything. Now I'm trying to create levels by loading two different tiled formats, but only one will load. Even if I try just loading 'level2.tmx', it won't work. Here is the code:

main.py
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1deCK3QED_e8uE4oRRECtizgTFMLvwbKN/view?usp=sharing

settings.py
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LvhnJCobweFT462PPXY42_FdnSF2UGs2/view?usp=sharing

sprites.py
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FD-Uj2SjMVNG29IcK5qaLoU6RBIB5I1s/view?usp=sharing

tilemap.py
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JeYiEo-xJHJ0I16geg7jNERAC5pqEIIH/view?usp=sharing

(By the way, in main.py(load_data), when it says to load tiled1.tmx, it should say level2.tmx.)

The error is this:

```
TMX compression type: zstd is not supported.
cannot load
done
```

It still loads level1.tmx, and the game goes on normally, but I cannot load level2.tmx, and if I try loading that to play, the screen does not load and it gives an error:

```
TMX compression type: zstd is not supported.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ruben\Documents\MAX\Python\Pygame\tileyLevel\main.py", line 285, in <module>
    g.new()
  File "C:\Users\ruben\Documents\MAX\Python\Pygame\tileyLevel\main.py", line 120, in new
    self.map = TiledMap(path.join(self.map_folder, 'level2.tmx'))
  File "C:\Users\ruben\Documents\MAX\Python\Pygame\tileyLevel\tilemap.py", line 22, in __init__
    tm = pytmx.load_pygame(filename, pixelalpha=True)
  File "C:\Users\ruben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pytmx\util_pygame.py", line 141, in load_pygame
    return pytmx.TiledMap(filename, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ruben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pytmx\pytmx.py", line 360, in __init__
    self.parse_xml(ElementTree.parse(self.filename).getroot())
  File "C:\Users\ruben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pytmx\pytmx.py", line 391, in parse_xml
    self.add_layer(TiledTileLayer(self, subnode))
  File "C:\Users\ruben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pytmx\pytmx.py", line 962, in __init__
    self.parse_xml(node)
  File "C:\Users\ruben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pytmx\pytmx.py", line 1044, in parse_xml
    raise Exception
Exception
```

If someone can help me, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I didn't have enough characters to put in the tmx files. Sorry about that!

Comment: can you please link the files to the post?

Comment: here they are (separate files for level 1 and 2)<https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RYuWDBFvnkmLvC8A0JcU5nEOAeZ5sBJS/view?usp=sharing> <https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VIh1kwsNqP3yjE5pLIRNF1D6BdGYCtes/view?usp=sharing>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the file, level2.tmx, is compressed with compression type zstd. This kind of compression is not supported by your python install.

If you install a python module to handle this kind of compression, such as the module at:
https://pypi.org/project/zstd/
It might work.

Alternatively you need to convert level2.tmx to the same format as level1.tmx

Comment: Great, thanks! I tried doing your first idea, it gave me an error. How do I convert level2.tmx to the same format as level1.tmx? They seem like the same format.

Comment: This is my first answer on stack overflow ever(well, it's my first question ever as well) so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an answer, but every time I kill the zombie, the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ruben\Documents\MAX\Python\Pygame\tileyLevel\main.py", line 295, in <module>
    g.run()
  File "C:\Users\ruben\Documents\MAX\Python\Pygame\tileyLevel\main.py", line 155, in run
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Users\ruben\Documents\MAX\Python\Pygame\tileyLevel\main.py", line 222, in draw
    self.screen.blit(self.map_img, self.camera.apply(self.map))
  File "C:\Users\ruben\Documents\MAX\Python\Pygame\tileyLevel\tilemap.py", line 49, in apply
          return entity.rect.move(self.camera.topleft)
AttributeError: 'TiledMap' object has no attribute 'rect'
```

appears. I don't know why this is. I know I should just edit the answer to do this, but there is no way I can do that. I need both the answers. The files are not too changed, but here they are:

settings.py
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ziel23c9GkB9kzcVOcrqiCVMq-RtfC2q/view?usp=sharing

tilemap.py
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12-Xh7P7llm5nGPqGt_CLkFbzU8LfWtBK/view?usp=sharing

main.py
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gUTQ30GI2bK6oUalA4T9hUwffphE4sun/view?usp=sharing

sprites.py
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EhHRkEzAJp6spKFMv-ar-jMSOy79DSjc/view?usp=sharing

level3.tmx(you already have level1 and level2)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E4FrrSNt6748mar77gV8nztU25z3oSfI/view?usp=sharing

level4.tmx
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pLB7j3rX3_YY2d_nv92zfZnXJSGoeoJa/view?usp=sharing

level24.tmx(It's a level 0, but I chose to write level24 instead, because it's not likely I'll have 24 levels. I can't be bothered to change the name.)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pLB7j3rX3_YY2d_nv92zfZnXJSGoeoJa/view?usp=sharing

Dungeons.tmx
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dGvWZ8EKf2WZ71k3RORTczjUIxRebec0/view?usp=sharing

This would be great if you could answer either this, or the question.

Comment: I checked someone else's problem. It was the same as mine. Now I've got levels!